# UIwebview iphone query

Tags: iphone

i have 2 question based on UIWEBVIEW

1) if i set **scaleToFitPage to YES,** it will shrink the page down and it is not readable , how to make default zoom level lets say 20

2) how to add button to UIwebview that will open my own viewController

**// UPDATES////////////////**

well zoom level is fixed now **looking for button link to ViewController**

**zoom level code:** < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />****

Answer (score 0):

finally its resolved

zoom level code: < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />**

and for call i created hyperlink
Thanks